# How to use Knn Imputer in Pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, scikit-learn, user-defined-functions

I want to use Knn Imputer in my Spark data Frame but it doesn't work well as I expected.

I have data that contain None data like below.

| group_num | days | time | useage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20200101 | 1 | 10.1 |
| 1 | 20200101 | 2 | 10.5 |
| 1 | 20200101 | 3 | null |
| 2 | 20200102 | 1 | 30 |
| 2 | 20200102 | 2 | null |
| 2 | 20200102 | 3 | null |
| 2 | 20200102 | 4 | 50.3 |
| 2 | 20200102 | 5 | null |
| 3 | 20200105 | 10 | null |
| 3 | 20200105 | 11 | null |
| 3 | 20200105 | 12 | 5.81 |

I have same data in pands as df_pandas and spark dataframe as df_spark.

I want to use sklearn KNNImputer to impute my None data in spark because using pandas is taking too much time due to my data size.

I try to use code below to solve my problem.

```
k_imputer = KNNImputer(n_neighbors = 7, weights = 'distance')
k_imputer.fit(df_pandas)


sc = spark.sparkContext

broadcast_model = sc.broadcast(k_imputer)

@udf('float')
def predict_data2(*cols):
    
    return float([i[3] for i in broadcast_model.value.transform((cols,))]  )

list_of_columns = df_pandas.columns
df_spark = df_spark.withColumn("pred", predict_data2(*list_of_columns))
```

What I was expected to above code is get impute pred column data like below.

| group_num | days | time | useage | pred |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20200101 | 1 | 10.1 | 10.1 |
| 1 | 20200101 | 2 | 10.5 | 10.5 |
| 1 | 20200101 | 3 | null | 5.6 |
| 2 | 20200102 | 1 | 30 | 30 |
| 2 | 20200102 | 2 | null | 12 |
| 2 | 20200102 | 3 | null | 22.12 |
| 2 | 20200102 | 4 | 50.3 | 50.3 |
| 2 | 20200102 | 5 | null | 2.2 |
| 3 | 20200105 | 10 | null | 7.1 |
| 3 | 20200105 | 11 | null | 23.1 |
| 3 | 20200105 | 12 | 5.81 | 5.81 |

but I got error

> float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'

I think I got something wrong in the udf function, but I don't know how to fix it.

Is there any solution to fix my problem?